# How to display a message box in python when entering a calendar?

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar

I have a task calendar  python program that allows the user to input a year and month which then displays the month calendar along with any task and the date its due.

However I am getting an error when I try to recall a method and tkMessageBox
Here is my code.

```
import calendar
from tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox




event = [8,10,17,21,29]
master = Tk()
Label(master, text =" Enter Year:").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text ="Enter Month").grid(row=1)


yy = Entry(master)
mm = Entry(master)

yy.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
mm.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


Button(master, text = 'Exit', command = master.exit).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 4)
Button(master, text = 'Submit', command = paybill(nn)).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 4)
mainloop()

#yy = int(input())
#mm = int(input())
#dd = int(input("Enter day: "))

print(calendar.month(yy,mm))


def bday(dd,mm):

    if(dd == 21 and mm == 2):
        print("Happy Birthday!")

    else:
        print("Unhappy Birthday!")

def paybill(nn):
    items = ["Insurance", "Netflix" , "Cell Phone"]
    if(nn == 2 or nn == 3):

        tkMessagBox.show(title="Calendar", message = str(items[0]) + " is due:" + " " + str(event[4]) + "th")
    elif(nn == 4 or nn == 5):
        print(str(items[0]) + " is due:" + " " + str(event[4]) + "th")
        print(str(items[2]) + " is due:" + " " + str(event[2]) + "th")

    else:
        print("Nothing is due this month")



#paybill(mm)
#e = str(input("Would You like to enter a new entry?"))

#def entry_date(e):
    #ne = []
   # if e == "Yes":
     #   int(input("Enter a date:"))
    #    event.append(e)
    #
     #   str(input("Enter a task"))
   #     ne.append(e)


  #  elif e == "No":
 #       print("No entry was added.")

#entry_date(e)

input ("Press Enter to Exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

`.show` does not appear to be a valid function of the `tkMessageBox`. Try one of the following instead.

> showinfo()
>
> showwarning()
>
> showerror ()
>
> askquestion()
>
> askokcancel()
>
> askyesno ()
>
> askretrycancel ()

See also:

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html

Comment: ok. i see now. I will try it. Also if I may ask another question. the command = paybill(nn) gets an error too. I'm not sure how to fix that either.

Comment: Please consider revising your original question to also include the new question **AND** the error message/stack trace. It's nearly impossible to assist you if you're not willing to spend the time to ask a good, concise question with specific problem statements...

Comment: i didn't know this was the rude.com . so you could be a bit nicer about it other wise don't reply back!

Comment: Last I checked, I'm the one giving you FREE advice. I'm simply asking that you follow the rules and expected etiquette here, there was nothing rude in my comment. If you want to have a pissing match, you're on your own.   Good luck.

Comment: I don't mean to argue but what you said made me feel dumb.

Comment: Perhaps rather than discussing your feels, you should consider what I asked you to do,  why I asked you to do it, and think about how that information might help me (or someone else) help you...

Comment: yes and I thank you for the advice . I was referring to this statement" if you're not willing to spend the time to ask a good, concise question with specific problem statements" this was the only part that I didn't like what you said.

Comment: your `paybill` function does not have a `return` statement, so it's returning a `None` type. That could be causing a problem, but without the error trace, it's hard to offer any more assistance.

Comment: Ok . Thank you so much.